# ¿Es aceptable "cónyugue" en lugar de "cónyuge"?

Tags: vocabulario, ortografía

Yo me acostumbré a decir *cónyugue* pero ahora [me entero que](http://www.blogolengua.com/2010/11/conyuge-conyugue-conyugal.html) no es correcto, el vocablo correcto es *cónyuge*.  Se oye raro a mi oído, y preferiría seguir diciendo *cónyugue*.  Entonces mi pregunta es, si va a dar mala impresión, por ejemplo en este sitio, decir *cónyugue*.

Comment: Yo de pequeño cuando aprendí esa palabra estuve muchos años diciendo _cónyugue_ hasta que me di cuenta de cómo era en realidad.

Comment: @Charlie - Bueno, pues, ¿cuál sería tu reacción de ver *cónyugue* acá, por ejemplo?  ¿Entrarías enseguida a corregir el post, o lo dejarías como variante aceptable?

Comment: Creo que debe ser uno de los pocos casos en que es más común escuchar la palabra mal dicha que escucharla bien.

Comment: Viene de *con-* y *yugo*; sería más lógico que preservara la /g/.

Comment: Yo siempre he oído decir *cónyuge* aunque es cierto que al leerla, mucho antes de escucharla por primera vez, decía *cónyugue* para mi mismo. No es una palabra que se utilice mucho fuera de formularios y cosas así.

Comment: El DPD http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=conyuge dice:  Cónyuge. ‘Consorte’. Es común en cuanto al género: el/la cónyuge (→ género2, 1a y 3c). Se pronuncia [kónyuje], no [kónyuge]; por tanto, no es correcta la grafía cónyugue.

Comment: @blonfu - Lo quiero usar en vez de *esposo* o *esposa* o *espos@* porque en línea no me gusta suponer el género del participante o su cónyuge.  (Ay, no me gusta como suena ni como se ve.)

Comment: @Cyanide - Ya acepté que debería ser *cónyuge*, pero como es un error tan universal, quiero saber si puedo seguir diciendo *cónyugue*, por ejemplo en este sitio.

Comment: ¿En la forma que quieres usarlo tienen que estar casados? Porque sino podrías decir *pareja* que sirve para ambos sexos y cualquier tipo de relación

Comment: @blonfu - gracias -- ¡problema resuelto!  Estaba buscando un equivalente de *spouse/partner* (inglés).  Pareja.  ¡Ya está!

Comment: ¿Qué? Oh por Dios, ¡siempre he dicho cónyugue!

Answer (score 6):

El DPD incluye [la siguiente entrada](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=c%C3%B3nyuge):

> **cónyuge**. ‘Consorte’. Es común en cuanto al género: *el/la cónyuge*. Se pronuncia [kónyuje], no ⊗[kónyuge]; por tanto, no es correcta la grafía ⊗*cónyugue*.

En todo caso, como ya he comentado yo mismo decía [kónyuge] al principio, antes de darme cuenta de que estaba metiendo una *u* donde no debería. Si yo viera que alguien escribe esa palabra:

1. Me sentiría identificado, dado que a mí me pasó lo mismo, y pensaría que la escribe así porque la ha oído pronunciada pero no escrita.
2. Corregiría la palabra y explicaría que es un error común por la facilidad de pronunciación de *cónyugue*, pero que en realidad la palabra no lleva esa *u* de más.

En todo caso, y precisamente porque es un error común, para nada me daría mala impresión. Es posible que el error hasta pase desapercibido por muchos.

De hecho es un error hasta con solera:

> *Adulterio es el engaño que se hace con un cónyugue ajeno.*
>
> Sebastián de Covarrubias, "Suplemento al Tesoro de la lengua española castellana", c 1611 (España).

Y también reciente:

> *Muchas veces esto obedece a la muerte prematura de uno de los cónyugues o por separación.*
>
> Judith E. Vivar Anaya, "Algunos aspectos de la cultura huarayo. Estructura familiar", 1970 (Perú).

En todo caso, los casos en textos escritos son demasiado pocos (menos de una decena en el CORDE y otros tantos en el CREA) como para que la RAE lo tenga en cuenta para su diccionario.

En todo caso, la solución al problema no es, digamos, *obligar* a los demás a aceptar tu forma de escribir la palabra, sino que a base de usarla y pronunciarla correctamente se te acabe quitando esa sensación de extrañeza y pases a verla como lo correcto y normal.

Comment: Gracias, esto me empieza a ayudar.  Pero siento un poco de confusión ahora por la pronunciación.  Mi problema no es por la ortografía.  Aprendí la palabra por oído a través de conversaciones, siempre se pronunciaba con la G dura de *gallo*.  ¿Cómo se pronuncia en tu entorno?

Comment: @aparente001 en mi entorno no se pronuncia apenas. Es una palabra formal, que solo aparece en contadísimas ocasiones. Igual puede ser que hasta lo viera escrito como _cónyuge_ en algún formulario y mi cabeza al verla por primera vez automáticamente pensara _cónyugue_ metiendo la _u_ de más. En todo caso, cada vez que la oigo suele ser en la tele (donde la pronuncian bien) en algún reportaje o algo.